# why is it is printing "Large Rat" instead of "Rat"

Tags: java

I'm teaching myself about classes in java and decided to try making my own class and use it in a program. To start, I have the following code:

```
public class Simulator {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Creature rat = new Creature(1, 12, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3);
        Creature poisonRat = new Creature(2, 16, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5);
        Creature largeRat = new Creature(5, 24, 10, 7, 4, 7, 10);

        rat.setCreatureName("Rat");
        poisonRat.setCreatureName("poisonous Rat");
        largeRat.setCreatureName("Large Rat");

        System.out.println(rat.getCreatureName());
    }

}
```

For some reason It is printing "Large Rat" instead of printing "Rat" and I don't know why. I am new with dealing with classes so I don't really know what I'm doing. Any ideas?

ok here is the Creature Class:

```
public class Creature {

    private String creatureName;
    private static int creatureLvl;
    private static double healthPoints;
    private static double strength;
    private static double magic;
    private static double defense;
    private static double magicDefense;
    private static double speed;

    public Creature (int lvl, double hp, double str, double mag, double def,      double magDef, double spd){
        creatureLvl = lvl;
        healthPoints = hp;
        strength = str;
        magic = mag;
        defense = def;
        magicDefense = magDef;
        speed = spd;
    }

    public String getCreatureName() {
        return creatureName;
    }

    public void setCreatureName(String creatureName) {
        creatureName = creatureName;
    }


}
```

Comment: the arguments for each "Creature" represent the attributes of the creature, such as health, level, strength, defense etc.

Comment: can you show `Creature` class, might be returning same instance from there

Comment: I suspect static field (it means that it is shared by class), Most beginners  tend to make their fields static just to get rid of compilation problem, where they are ask to not refer non-static content from main method. BTW there can be also other reasons of always seeing "Large Rat", but without seeing your code all we can do is guess.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, probably CreatureName is static.

Comment: Without even looking at your code I can tell you that the name of the `Creature` is stored in a `static` variable, meaning that it is shared among all *instances* of `Creature`. Making it non-static will fix this problem.

Comment: there are a lot of comments here with valid suggestions. However to be a usefull post (usefull to others in the future) it would help if Luis Torres just shows us the source code of the Creature class. Until than my added value will not be more than any of the previous posts.

Comment: To update your question with your code use [edit] option.

Comment: If you post code to your question, then please post your _real_ code and not some altered code after reading some comments/answers without mentioning that this code isn't the original one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have declared `creatureName` in the `Creature` class as a [`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) field:

```
private static String creatureName;
```

This means that it is a field which is shared among all instances of the class; if you change the field via one instance, it will be changed in all others. Change to

```
private String creatureName;
```

and you should be fine.

EDIT:

Also, in a setter method, if the field has the same name as the parameter, you need to use `this.`:

```
public void setCreatureName(String creatureName) {
    this.creatureName = creatureName;
}
```

Comment: @vinayakj Static fields can also be accessed through *non*-static functions. Heck, even `setCreatureName` could have been declared as a static function.

Comment: @vinayakj static fields are accessed via class like `SomeClass.staticField`. You can *assess that class from any place* (assuming it is public class). You can also try using `reference.staticField` but it is same as using `ClassOfReference.staticField`.

Comment: I will show you the creature class:

Comment: It won't let me show the Creature class It's too long apparently for a comment

Comment: @LuisTorres I hope you will update your question with your code, and not try to post it as comment under some answer. Let others see it in proper form (comments won't allow formatting) and let them see it right away (don't make answerers search for important informations under answers - place them in your question).

Comment: I made the creature so that it isn't a static variable but if I do that the output of the main method comes out as "null"

Comment: @LuisTorres use `this.creatureName` to set value

Comment: @LuisTorres Post your code in your question. Without it we can only guess what is wrong with it, and that is not very effective.

Comment: sorry pshemo I just did it.

Comment: @vinayakj it worked thanks. Sorry about not sending the code for the class. I didn't think the problem was in the class. Thank you all for your patience! :)

Comment: @LuisTorres while you're still busy, remove the `static` keyword from *all* fields.

Comment: @Glorfindel I wondered if that would be necessary too. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That's not necessary for your code to work *right now*, but you will get into trouble later. Please make sure you understand the difference between instance members and class members (see for example the link in my answer).